# Jenkins build history issue

Tags: jenkins

I am facing a weird issue after upgrading jenkins to 1.632. After upgrade I am not able to see the build history in jenkins and surprise thing is that history is lost for few jobs. I have reverted back the jenkins but still I am not able to see the history. To make this issue more clear I am running Jenkins on tomcat and I just replace the jenkins.war file in webapps directory. I believe it should not have any impact on JENKINS_HOME location. Is there any way to restore the build history? BTW I also tried the option "reload configuration from the disk" but that is also not working. I am running jenkins on Linux box.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Comment: Can you check the retention policy for build logs for those jobs that have lost logs? This should be available from job config. Also, are those logs available from disk directly?

Comment: How I can check the retention policy for build logs? I am not able to see the directory in format of date-time but I am able to see the directory with build number under builds directory. This build number directory contains the logs.

Comment: You can check the retention policy for the build records of a job by going to the job configuration page and looking at `Discard old builds`. It is at the very beginning of the config page.

Comment: "Days to keep the build" is empty and the max # of builds to keep "2" and rest of the steps are also empty.

Comment: So you'll see a grand total of 2 latest builds at any time, unless you change this to whatever other setting or press `Keep this build forever` for builds you intend to keep, which will do what it says and not count for overall max nr builds to keep. I don't think I can help you to determine the root cause for this, but: are you the only person managing Jenkins or could someone set this setting and not inform you? I don't think it is possible that Jenkins upgrade changed this, but this theoretically may be the cause. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Zloj. Yes I am the only person who is managing jenkins in terms of administration perspective. Other team members can create and configure the jobs. I notice that the history of all the jobs for which "Days to keep the build" is empty is not available in jenkins. I also think that Jenkins update should not have any impact on this. Not quite sure what cause this and how to fix this.

Comment: You won't be able to restore the build records unless you can afford the hard drive restoration, but even if you go this way - there's no assurance that those logs were'nt already physically overwritten by some other data on disk. I think this has already happend with a 99% chance.  You can prevent this in future by setting the retention policy to a longer than 2 days term.

Comment: Thanks Zloj for your help.